# How to format unix time (sec+usec+nsec) string?

Tags: c++, linux, time

I have this function which works just fine. It gives me current system time the way I need:

```
struct Timer
{
    struct timespec ts;
    char buff[16];
    char res[64];

public:
    char* GetTimestampNow()
    {
        timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
        strftime(buff, sizeof buff, "%T", gmtime(&ts.tv_sec));
        snprintf(res, 64, "%s.%09ld", buff, ts.tv_nsec);

        return res;
    }
    char* GetTimestamp(int sec, int usec) {
        // ??? how do I convert raw readings into timespec or anything else I can use in strftime?
        strftime(buff, sizeof buff, "%T", gmtime(&ts.tv_sec));
        snprintf(res, 64, "%s.%09ld", buff, ts.tv_nsec);

        return res;
    }
    char* GetTimestamp(int sec, int usec, int nsec) {
        // same question plus nanosecs
};
```

Now I need to also be able to print timestamps I receive from 3rd party lib in 2-3 variables  - sec, usec, nsec (optional). Can I somehow construct `timespec` from these values and reuse the code I already have?

Comment: On an unrelated note, why do you return pointers to arrays? Why not `std::string`?

Comment: Another unrelated note: Why not use `chrono`? Making your own class mimic some parts of `chrono` wouldn't be hard though. Add a `static` function that returns a `Timer` with the `ts` set to the current time, then just add conversion functions. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/deGfMv41f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `timespec` structure.

Notice how all the `gmtime` calls only use the `tv_sec` field of the structure? You can use the `sec` argument directly in the `gmtime` call.

As for the nanoseconds, you could multiply `usec` with `1000` to get the corresponding nanoseconds.

So something like:

```
char buff[16];  // No need to make this a member variable, it can be local
strftime(buff, sizeof buff, "%T", gmtime(&sec));
snprintf(res, 64, "%s.%09ld", buff, usec * 1000);
```

In the third overload, just add `nsec` to the result of `usec * 1000`.

---

I would rather recommend you create a utility function for the creation of the string, which all the other functions are calling.

Like

```
class Timer
{
public:
    std::string GetTimestampNow()
    {
        timespec ts;
        timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
        return GetTimestampHelper(ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
    }

    std::string GetTimestamp(time_t sec, long usec)
    {
        return GetTimestampHelper(sec, usec * 1000);
    }

    std::string GetTimestamp(time_t sec, long usec, long nsec)
    {
        return GetTimestampHelper(sec, usec * 1000 + nsec);
    }

private:
    std::string GetTimestampHelper(time_t sec, long nsec)
    {
        char buff[64];
        strftime(buff, sizeof buff, "%T", gmtime(&sec));

        char res[64];
        snprintf(res, sizeof res, "%s.%09ld", buff, nsec);

        return res;
    }
};
```

And unless there's code and requirements not mentioned, there's really no need for these member functions to be non-static.

And the `Timer` names implies something like stop-watch, so the class should probably be renamed as well.